# What languages provide the use of object literals?

Tags: programming-languages, object-literal

What languages provide the use of object literals? (Or in what languages could you easily emulate them?) Can you give a code example?

Starting with the obvious javascript snippet:

```
var someObj = {
    someProperty: 123,
    someFunction: function() {
        alert('hello!');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace object by "term," then Prolog does this naturally (in fact, there's no other way to construct an object). Here's an example featuring binary trees:

```
% find a node in List with a nil left child and call its rightmost grandchild X
member(node(nil,node(_,X)), List).
```

Lisp and Scheme also have some pretty advances features in this area, particularly quoting and semiquoting:

```
;; construct right-leaning binary tree with x as the rightmost grandchild
`(nil . (nil . ,x))
```

Practically all functional programming languages have copied this in some form.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout C# anonymous types

```
var Customer = new
{
    Company = "AgileApps",
    Website = "http://www.agileapps.co.uk",
    Name = "Big Al",
    Entered = DateTime.Now
};
```